# Is it bad practice to have interface methods return objects or Types?

Tags: java, interface

Say there is a class called `Thing`.

Would it be a bad practice to have an interface return a Thing?

```
interface Doable{
  public Thing generateThing();
}
```

What if Thing wasn't a class, but just another interface (Type).  Would this be a bad practice?

Thanks.

Comment: why would that be bad?

Comment: It´s Java not C++, return value would be a reference and for such it doesn´t meter if it´s a class or an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule you return the most general type that makes sense for the use case. For instance, imagine if you wanted to return a collection of things:

`Collection` is usually too general, people using the collection usually need to know what kind of collection it is.

`ArrayList` on the other hand is most often too specific, users of your interface don't usually care how your list stores it's values internally.

`List` then is perfect. Which is an interface.

So no. Why would it be a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a bad practice, but you have better to consider the context.
You should understand which is the expected implementation and ask yourself if the code will be easily reusable